# Maven3 : when groupId is renamed, will it cause any conflict or errors

Tags: java, maven-3

When renaming a groupId in maven will it cause any unexpected conflict or errors?

e.g from

```
<groupId>com.current.id</groupId>
```

to

```
<groupId>com.new.newid</groupId>
```

I already tried to build it with maven clean install, it's **Build Success** but I wanted to ask so I won't encounter any problems later on.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, there shouldn't be any errors al long as the coordinates of your artifact are unique. As the coordinates of your artifact are made up of groupId, artifactId, ... it should be no problem, but ensure that there is no other artifact with the same artifactId in the group with your new groupId.

Comment: Thanks, this clarified my question.

Answer (score 0):

If the project with the renamed groupId is a dependency of other projects, you had to fix the groupId in the dependencies section of these projects too.

Apart from that, you should delete the project with the groupId com.current.id in your repository (the local repository is located at /[home_dir]/.m2/repository) and rebuild any projects using your project as dependency to see if it everything is correctly resolved.